# Total size of all subsets of a set is $n\cdot2^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

So I'm supposed to show that the total size of all subsets of a set is $n\cdot2^{n-1}$. I've noted that $2^{n-1}$ is the size of the power set of an $n-1$ element set, and I think it's that every element of $P(X)$ where $|X|=n-1$ will contribute $n$ to the size of the subsets of $P(X')$ where $|X'| = n$ but I don't know why or how. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the total size of all subsets"?

Comment: Like for the subsets of {1,2}, you add up 1 subset of size 0, the empty set, 2 subsets of size 1, and 1 subset of size 2, you get 4, which is 2*2^1 = 4.

Comment: How does that work for $\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: 1 subset of size 0, 3 subsets of size 1, 3 subsets of size 2, and 1 subset of size 3... oh wow. That's awesome. I think I see it now! EDIT: Oh wait I think that's just a result of the binomial theorem...

Comment: You want $\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}$. There are many questions on MSE in which it is shown the sum is $n2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine we have a list of all the subsets of the $n$-element set $A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$.  We find the sum of their sizes in a funny way.

Look first at $a_1$, and make a tick mark for every one of the subsets of $A$ that $a_1$ occurs in. We will make $2^{n-1}$ tick marks, since $2^{n-1}$ subsets of $A$ contain $a_1$.

Do the same for all the $a_i$. The total number of tick marks is the sum of the sizes of the subsets of $A$. For given any subset $S$ of $A$, our procedure produces a tick mark for every member of $S$.

The total number of tick marks is $n2^{n-1}$.

**Remark:** We are evaluating the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}$. There are a number of proofs on MSE that this sum is $n2^{n-1}$. We described a counting argument specifically suited to the "sum of sizes" version.

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: Sorry, can you explain why each element will appear 2^(n-1) times? Is it because that's the size of the powers set of a set of n-1 elements, and a1 will appear in every subset of the n-1 element set in the power set of the n element set? Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: To make a subset of $A$ that contains $a_1$, we take the union of $\{a_1\}$ with **any** subset of $A\setminus\{a_1\}$. There are $2^{n-1}$ subsets of this set. More informally, half of the $2^n$ subsets of $A$ contain $a_1$, and half don't.

Comment: Taking the derivative of $(1+x)^n$, and plugging in $x=1$ would be another way.

Comment: @i707107: Yes, that is a nice way to do it, please consider giving it as an answer. I wanted to give a "pure counting" argument.

Answer (score 10):

Each subset and its complement together have exactly $n$ elements.

Comment: This is just a hint--but a very good one. +1.

Comment: Nice pairing argument.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are more elegant.  But the most straightforward way is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} i
= \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n! \cdot i}{i!(n-i)!}
= n \sum_{i=1}^n {n-1 \choose i-1}
= n 2^{n-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^k\iff f'(x)=n\,(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^nk{n\choose k}x^{k-1}$$

$$f'(1)=n\cdot2^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^nk{n\choose k}$$

Answer (score 0):

The total size is $\#\{\,(x,S)\in X\times\mathcal P(X)\mid x\in S\,\}$ if you count by fixing each$~S\subseteq X$ first. But counting fixing each $x\in X$ first, it contributes $\#\mathcal P(X\setminus\{x\})=2^{n-1}$ to this size, for a total of $n2^{n-1}$.